# Image and Title to UIbutton is not being set

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I'm trying to implement an image as well as title on UIButton. Size of UIButton is 86 x 96. I need to embed an image of size 86 x 76 on top and title of size 86 x 20 just below the image.

The code is

```
UIButton *generalButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[generalButton setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
generalButton.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:13];
[generalButton setImageEdgeInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0,0,20,0)];
[generalButton setTitleEdgeInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(76,0,0,0)];
generalButton.frame = CGRectMake(32,20,86,96);
[generalButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"flower_icon.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[generalButton setTitle:@"Flower" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self addSubview:generalButton];
```

But the problem is that only image is being shown, whereas the title is not showing up. And if I hide the image by commenting the code, then title shows up perfectly.

Please Help

Comment: You are setting setTitleColor as while color and what is your back ground color for button? please change title color and check it. And one more thing check insets value for image and title may be title will go out of frame when image shown.

Comment: Background color for button is dark Gray Color

Comment: Please check my answer as below I posted it. Check if it working or not. :)

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

```
 UIButton *generalButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[generalButton setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
generalButton.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:13];
[generalButton setImageEdgeInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0,0,20,0)];
[generalButton setTitleEdgeInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(30,-50,0,0)];
generalButton.frame = CGRectMake(32,20,86,96);
[generalButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"RepresentativeIcon.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[generalButton setTitle:@"Flower" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.view addSubview:generalButton];
```

Comment: It's the same thing, moreover using "setBackgroundImage" will cover whole button with that image.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code:

```
UIButton *generalButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [generalButton setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    generalButton.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:13];
    [generalButton setImageEdgeInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(20,22,20,0)];
    [generalButton setTitleEdgeInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(50,-30,0,0)];
    generalButton.frame = CGRectMake(32,20,86,96);
    [generalButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor yellowColor]];
    [generalButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Facebook"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [generalButton setTitle:@"Flower" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.view addSubview:generalButton];
```

Note:

```
[generalButton setImageEdgeInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(20,22,20,0)];
[generalButton setTitleEdgeInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(50,-30,0,0)];
```

These two line are performing main role to repositioning your title and image so set all parameters as per your image height & width and title length.

In this code I change image name as I have and also changed back colour of button so please change according to your data.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: I need image to be of size 86(width) x 76(height) on the top. So I've set image Edge inset to (0,0,20(bottom),0). And just below the image I need the titleLabel to be of size 86(width) x 20(height), hence imageEdgeInset for title is (76(top since it is covered by image),0,0,0).

Comment: do you find any kind of error while setting edge insets in code above?

Comment: No I didn't find any error. Here all you have to play with insert only else other code is all correct.